# jQuery regexp validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, forms, validation

I would like to validate user input client side with a little jQuery function that is called onsubmit on my form. I want the field #fname (first name) to only allow a-z, A-Z and space. The return false is supposed to be stopping the form from submitting.

```
function validateregister(){
    if (!($("fname") =~ [a-zA-Z ])) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This is my HTML:

```
<input type="submit" value="Join now!" id="registersubmit" class="paddingoutline2" onsubmit="return validateregister()">
```

Of course, i'm going to validate the user input on the server side later on. When I submit the form, it gives me an "internal server error". This makes me think that I made an error in my function validateregister(). Is there anything wrong? If the I'm pretty new to jQuery so any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: The `=~` is Perl syntax, not Javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is

```
function validateregister(){
    return /^[a-zA-Z ]+$/.test($('#fname').val());
}
```

Apart fixing the selector suggesting the use of the `val` and [test](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) functions, I took the liberty to change the regex :

- `^` and `$` force the test to cover the whole string
- the `+` requires at least one character

But are you aware that this regex might be too strict if you want people to type their real first name ? Yours, for example, would not pass...

Comment: That's something I had not thought about, you're absolutely right i'm missing a lot of characters. Thanks for pointing that out!

Is it normal that it returns false and that the webpage still submits the form? I would like it to stay on the same webpage and only show an error message.

Comment: `onsubmit` should be on the `form` element, not on the `submit` one.

Comment: De rien, ce fut un plaisir ;)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use regex this way:

```
function validateregister(){
    var nameRgx = /[a-zA-Z]/;
    var phoneRgx = /[0-9]/;
    if (!nameRgx.test($("#fname").val())) {
       return false;
    }
    if (!phoneRgx.test($("#phone").val())) {
       return false;
    }
}
```

And make sure to refer your elements with Either with `#` id notation or `.` class notation. In your code you are not referencing your elem in a proper way.

```
^ ---->Start of a string. 
$ ---->End of a string. 
. ----> Any character (except \n newline) 
{...}----> Explicit quantifier notation. 
[...] ---->Explicit set of characters to match. 
(...) ---->Logical grouping of part of an expression. 
* ---->0 or more of previous expression. 
+ ---->1 or more of previous expression. 
? ---->0 or 1 of previous expression; 
       also forces minimal matching when an expression might 
       match several strings within a search string.
```

[More Info about Regex writing](http://geekswithblogs.net/brcraju/archive/2003/10/23/235.aspx)